# AngularJS http get pass nothing to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why in function `Login(string email,string password)` `email` is null and `password` also null.

JavaScript:

```
$http({
      method: "GET",
      url: '/Home/Login/',
      dataType: "json",
      params: JSON.stringify({ email: 'Test', password: 'Test' })
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
});
```

HomeController:

```
    public JsonResult Login(string email,string password)
    {
        return Json("working",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you still using the [`.success()` callback](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server expecting the params as query parameters but you are sending as JSON string. Change your line

```
params: JSON.stringify({ email: 'Test', password: 'Test' })
```

to

```
params: { email: 'Test', password: 'Test' }
```

And remove `dataType: "json",`

*Tip*: Like @Phil & @Sateh mentioned, don't use `success` or `error` methods instead use `then` method. So your code will look like this:

```
$http({
      method: "GET",
      url: '/Home/Login/',
      params: { email: 'Test', password: 'Test' }
}).then(function(response) {
      alert(response.data);
}, function() {
      console.log("Error occured");
});
```

Comment: You can't just replace `.success()` and `.error()` with the same callbacks in `then()`. The argument to each is entirely different; it's the full `response` object, not just the `data`